# Matlab Prime number list checker

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Ok so I have been having a go at creating a prime number checker. I have been successful in making it work for a specific number. The code is here.

```
#To test if number is prime

prompt = input("number to test if prime: ");
n = prompt;
i = 2; #start of mod test
t = floor(sqrt(n));
counter = 0;
tic
for i = 2:t
  if mod(n,i) == 0 
    disp('n is not prime')
    break
  else
    counter = (counter + 1);
  end
end

if counter == t-1
  disp('n is prime')
end
toc
```

I then tried to make a program which would test a range of numbers. It's been successful for n=10, but when I go higher than that it doesn't seem to pick up the primes. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
#Want to test numbers 2:n if they're prime

prompt = input("max number to test: ");
n = prompt;
l = 2; #start of mod test
counter = 0;
tic

for i = 2:n #cycle to test 2 up to n
  t = floor(sqrt(i)) #Only need to test up to root of number
  for l = 2:t
    if mod(i,l) == 0 
      break
    else
      counter = (counter + 1);
      end
  end
  if counter == t-1 # if tested up to the root of the number, it must be prime
    prime = sprintf('%d is prime', round(i));
    disp(prime)
    counter = 0;
  end
end
toc
```

Any help in getting it to work for larger values would be greatly appreciated and also any ways to make the code more efficient. The top program can test 982451653 in 0.268 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: Is this 1) for fun? 2) for class? 3) or you actually need a prime number checker?

Comment: Just for fun :) Trying to get better at matlab before college starts again!

Comment: A tip for making it more efficient: If a number cannot be divided by 2 then it won't be for 4, 6, 8... so you can reduce a lot the number of checks. Similarly for 3, 6, 9, etc...

Comment: why not simply use [**`isprime`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isprime.html)?

Comment: Thanks for that Sembei, I'll try and implement it.

Comment: And I know what you mean Sadar, but I'm trying to improve my coding skills so wanted to see if I could code it myself. Also I wanted to see if I could do it faster, for example isprime(982451653) takes 0.273 sec while my code took 0.268 and I think I could make it a good bit faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a way to linearize your algorithm:

```
n = 997 %test number
t1 = n./([2,3:2:n/2]);
t2 = t1 - round(t1);
res = sum(t2 == 0); %can n be divided ? 

if res == 0
    fprintf('%s','prime');
else
    fprintf('%s','not prime');
end
```

Comment: Hi obchardon, thanks for the code. First of all, how does the matrix work? (it looked really interesting when I put it into matlab),I put it into what I had earlier. It worked at finding a lot of primes. But I also got some false positives like 4,8,16,64. Is 4 not covered in that above code? this is what I used [code]    prompt = input("max number to test: ");
n = prompt;

for i = 2:n
  t1 = i./(3:2:i/2);
  t2 = t1 - round(t1);
  res = find(t2 == 0,1); %can n be divided ? 

    if size(res,2) == 0
      prime = sprintf('%d is prime', round(i));
      disp(prime)
    end
end [/code]

Comment: @JamesBlackwell ho my bad, I didn't check if the test number was an even number or not, now it's fixed :) It's similar to your algorithm, I just check if the test number can be divided by [2,3,5,7,9,11... n/2]. With the `./` operator you can divide a single number by an array in Matlab, then the code just check if it exist a division with no rest.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I would upvote but still need to increase my rep first. Its a very clean way to check it :)

Answer (score 0):

I got help on the issue and found that 'counter' was constantly re-setting and needed to be moved up. Fixed code is here

```
#Want to test numbers 2:n if they're prime

prompt = input("max number to test: ");
n = prompt;
l = 2; #start of mod test
counter = 0;
tic

for i = 2:n #cycle to test 2 up to n
  t = floor(sqrt(i)); #Only need to test up to root of number
  counter = 0;
  for l = 2:t
    if mod(i,l) == 0 
      break
    else
      counter = (counter + 1);
      end
  end
  if counter == t-1; # if tested up to the root of the number, it must be prime
    prime = sprintf('%d is prime', round(i));
    disp(prime)

  end
end
toc
```